# How to read propositions with more than two nested quantifiers?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

I am given the proposition:
$$\forall x \forall y \exists z\ (z = (x \cdot y))$$

It's not clear to me whether I am to interpret this as

> For all `x` and For all `y`, there exists a `z` where `(z = (x * y))` is true

Where this is can be thought of as one node in set `z` being related to every node in sets `x` and `y`, equivalent to $\forall x \exists z \land \forall y \exists z$ ; a one-to-many relationship twice where `z` is the 'one' both times.

or if it should be interpreted as

> For all `x`, it will be the case that For all `y`, there exists a `z` where `(z = (x * y))` is true

Where I guess an example could be "For every number, it will be true that for every number, there will be a number that when divided by 0 is equal to 0", but there doesn't seem to be a meaningful relationship between between the first universal quantifier and the second.

Comment: It's the second one. I.e. choose any $x$, then choose any $y$, and for that ordered pair $(x,y)$, you can find a $z$ that makes the inside statement true.

Comment: I don't understand why *For all* `x` *and For all* `y`, *there exists a* `z` is to be equivalent to $\forall x \exists z \land \forall y \exists z.$ Linguistically, the former is understood as "(for all x and for all y) there exists z", which is made even more forceably by the placement of the single comma in the former. The only issue I see is whether the existence of $z$ follows from a choice of an unordered pair $\{x,y\}$ or from a choice of an ordered pair $(x,y),$ since when written in words we don't know whether commutativity of "and" is implicitly assumed.

Comment: The example above is quite easy. It formalizes the fact that for every two numbers there is their product: "for every number x and for every number y there is a number z such that z is the product of x and y".

Comment: We can prove that $\forall x \forall y$ and $\forall y \forall x$ are equivalent. Not so for $\forall x \exists z$ and $\exists z \forall x$.